# Compare nested Json data with excel columns

Tags: python, json, dataframe

```
"Services": {
"RoadAttributes": {
  "egoInformation": [
    {
      "roundabout": {
        "id": 5,
        "value1": 5,
        "source": 5
      },
      "tollStation": {
        "id": 5,
        "value1": 5,
        "source": 5
      },
      "railroadcrossing": {
        "id": 5,
        "value1": 5,
        "source": 5
      },
      "speedbump": {
        "id": 5,
        "value1": 5,
        "source": 5
      },
      "tunnel": {
        "id": 5,
        "value1": 5,
        "source": 5
      },
      "urbanArea": {
        "id": 5,
        "value1": 5,
        "source": 5
      },
      "streetClass": {
        "id": 5,
        "value1": 5,
        "source": 5
      },
      "functionalRoadClass": {
        "id": 5,
        "value1": 5,
        "source": 5
      },
      "constructionSite": {
        "id": 5,
        "value1": 5,
        "source": 5
      },
      "laneIndexEgo": {
        "id": 5,
        "value1": 5,
        "source": 5
      },
      "laneNumbers": {
        "id": 5,
        "value1": 5,
        "value2": 5,
        "source": 5
      },
      "laneAcceleration": {
        "id": 5,
        "value1": 5,
        "value2": 5,
        "source": 5
      },
      "laneDeceleration": {
        "id": 5,
        "value1": 5,
        "value2": 5,
        "value3": 5,
        "source": 5
      },
      "laneWidth": {
        "id": 5,
        "value1": 5,
        "source": 5
      },
      "structuralSeperation": {
        "id": 5,
        "value1": 5,
        "source": 5
      },
      "ramp": {
        "id": 5,
        "value1": 5,
        "source": 5
      },
      "insideCity": {
        "id": 5,
        "value1": 5,
        "source": 5
      },
      "crosswalk": {
        "id": 5,
        "value1": 5,
        "source": 5
      },
      "intersection": {
        "id": 5,
        "value1": 5,
        "value2": 5,
        "source": 5
      },
      "relativeYawAngle": 5,
      "messageCounter": 4
    }
  ]
}}
```

Json data to be compared with excel columns [image]

```py
import json
import json as js

# Read the JSON file
with open("ampmin.json") as f:
    data = js.load(f)

# Temp_Data=data['Services']
# print(Temp_Data)
for d in data:
    Temp_Data = d['Services']
```

I did tried with above code and tried to read the json, there are lot of services entries in my json file I want compare them with my excel parameters if match found notify us, but not getting how to optimistically retrieve the parameters and compare with excel parameters? any help would be appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: To navigate to the `id` you appear to be looking for you just want `d['Services']['RoadAttributes']['egoinformation']['roundabout']['id']`, no?

Comment: I tried this already, Getting error TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Comment: My excel does have lot of same entries It should search for Json data in Json file which exactly matches row data in excel

Comment: @Malcolm I think you need `[0]` after `['egoinformation']` because `egoinformation` is a list - `d['Services']['RoadAttributes']['egoinformation'][0]['roundabout']['id']`. Of course it would need `for`-loop to check `[0]`, `[1]`, `[2]`, etc.

Comment: you have JSON with nested data - so you may need nested `for`-loops. You could use `type()` in every loop to check if you have `list` or `dict` and create nested loop `for item in list` or `for key, val in dict.items()`

Comment: @furas is correct.  I missed that the  `'egoinformation'` block had a set of square brackets around the dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what you want to compare ...

... but if you have nested `JSON` then you need nested `for`-loops.

In every `for`-loop you can use `type()` to check what you have in nested element - `list` or `dict` - and decide if you need to use `for item in list` or `for key, val in dict.items()`

This code

```
data = {"Services": {
"RoadAttributes": {
  "egoInformation": [
    {
      "roundabout": {
        "id": 5,
        "value1": 5,
        "source": 5
      },
      "tollStation": {
        "id": 5,
        "value1": 5,
        "source": 5
      },
      "railroadcrossing": {
        "id": 5,
        "value1": 5,
        "source": 5
      },
      "speedbump": {
        "id": 5,
        "value1": 5,
        "source": 5
      },
      "tunnel": {
        "id": 5,
        "value1": 5,
        "source": 5
      },
      "urbanArea": {
        "id": 5,
        "value1": 5,
        "source": 5
      },
      "streetClass": {
        "id": 5,
        "value1": 5,
        "source": 5
      },
      "functionalRoadClass": {
        "id": 5,
        "value1": 5,
        "source": 5
      },
      "constructionSite": {
        "id": 5,
        "value1": 5,
        "source": 5
      },
      "laneIndexEgo": {
        "id": 5,
        "value1": 5,
        "source": 5
      },
      "laneNumbers": {
        "id": 5,
        "value1": 5,
        "value2": 5,
        "source": 5
      },
      "laneAcceleration": {
        "id": 5,
        "value1": 5,
        "value2": 5,
        "source": 5
      },
      "laneDeceleration": {
        "id": 5,
        "value1": 5,
        "value2": 5,
        "value3": 5,
        "source": 5
      },
      "laneWidth": {
        "id": 5,
        "value1": 5,
        "source": 5
      },
      "structuralSeperation": {
        "id": 5,
        "value1": 5,
        "source": 5
      },
      "ramp": {
        "id": 5,
        "value1": 5,
        "source": 5
      },
      "insideCity": {
        "id": 5,
        "value1": 5,
        "source": 5
      },
      "crosswalk": {
        "id": 5,
        "value1": 5,
        "source": 5
      },
      "intersection": {
        "id": 5,
        "value1": 5,
        "value2": 5,
        "source": 5
      },
      "relativeYawAngle": 5,
      "messageCounter": 4
    }
  ]
}}
}

for s1_key, s1_val in data['Services'].items():
    #print(s1_key, type(s1_val))
    for s2_key, s2_val in s1_val.items():
        #print(s2_key, type(s2_val))
        for s3_items in s2_val:
            #print('[0]', type(s3_items))
            for s4_key, s4_val in s3_items.items():
                #print(s4_key, type(s4_val))
                print(s1_key, s2_key, f'{s4_key:20}', s4_val)
```

Gives me:

```
RoadAttributes egoInformation roundabout           {'id': 5, 'value1': 5, 'source': 5}
RoadAttributes egoInformation tollStation          {'id': 5, 'value1': 5, 'source': 5}
RoadAttributes egoInformation railroadcrossing     {'id': 5, 'value1': 5, 'source': 5}
RoadAttributes egoInformation speedbump            {'id': 5, 'value1': 5, 'source': 5}
RoadAttributes egoInformation tunnel               {'id': 5, 'value1': 5, 'source': 5}
RoadAttributes egoInformation urbanArea            {'id': 5, 'value1': 5, 'source': 5}
RoadAttributes egoInformation streetClass          {'id': 5, 'value1': 5, 'source': 5}
RoadAttributes egoInformation functionalRoadClass  {'id': 5, 'value1': 5, 'source': 5}
RoadAttributes egoInformation constructionSite     {'id': 5, 'value1': 5, 'source': 5}
RoadAttributes egoInformation laneIndexEgo         {'id': 5, 'value1': 5, 'source': 5}
RoadAttributes egoInformation laneNumbers          {'id': 5, 'value1': 5, 'value2': 5, 'source': 5}
RoadAttributes egoInformation laneAcceleration     {'id': 5, 'value1': 5, 'value2': 5, 'source': 5}
RoadAttributes egoInformation laneDeceleration     {'id': 5, 'value1': 5, 'value2': 5, 'value3': 5, 'source': 5}
RoadAttributes egoInformation laneWidth            {'id': 5, 'value1': 5, 'source': 5}
RoadAttributes egoInformation structuralSeperation {'id': 5, 'value1': 5, 'source': 5}
RoadAttributes egoInformation ramp                 {'id': 5, 'value1': 5, 'source': 5}
RoadAttributes egoInformation insideCity           {'id': 5, 'value1': 5, 'source': 5}
RoadAttributes egoInformation crosswalk            {'id': 5, 'value1': 5, 'source': 5}
RoadAttributes egoInformation intersection         {'id': 5, 'value1': 5, 'value2': 5, 'source': 5}
RoadAttributes egoInformation relativeYawAngle     5
RoadAttributes egoInformation messageCounter       4
```

Comment: Thanks @furas...It did worked ..I just wanted compare excel column data with json data if it is found in json file assign the json data to global variables and come out of the loop for further processing

Comment: Hi @Furas , awaiting for your response, thanks!

Comment: so in place of `print()` in my code you have to compare values `s1_key, s2_key, s4_key', s4_val` with values in `Excel`

Comment: Here is my updated code: `for i, (SR, SR1, SR2, EL, min) in enumerate(
        zip(Source_Path, Dest_Path, Task_ID,Description, Label)):

    for d in data:
        Temp_Data = d['Services']
        if len (Temp_Data)!= 0:
            for s1_key, s1_val in Temp_Data.items():
                 print("")
                # print(s1_key)

    if (s1_key == SR):
        print(SR)`  Here I am only getting last word match, not all the keys present in services from json and excel file. I am reading column data with function read_excelcolumn SR,SR1,SR2,EL,Min iterators

Comment: better add it to your question. It will be more readable. And more people can see it - so more people may help you. And describe it for other people.